# Sony XPeria T service menu app missing

Tags: bootloader, sony-xperia, bootloader-lock

I just found out that I have a Sony XPeria T, not a Sony XPeria Z1 Compact. After years of owning it. Wow.
So I wanted to try some things that I previously discarded because they weren't possible with the Z1 Compact. One of those things is unlocking the bootloader.

So I went to [the official Sony page for that](https://developer.sony.com/develop/open-devices/get-started/unlock-bootloader#unlock-code) and entered the code they gave me: `*#*#7378423#*#*`
The result of that: It disappears from the phone app as soon as I enter the last `*`. The service menu does not open. So I look in my apps list: No service menu. Apps like "Service menu for XPeria" also can't open it.
I also can't find a working apk for it online.

**So how do I get the confusingly named "Rooting Status" that tells me whether I can unlock the bootloader on that device?**

I'm using the preinstalled Android 4.3, but rooted and with XPosed. I uninstalled a few system apps, but definitely not the service menu. The model number is LT30p.

Comment: I'd rather avoid the check, go ahead, get the key and try to flash it and issue the unlock command. If it unlocks, then good. Else, it can't be unlocked 

Comment: The problem with that is the reason why I didn't do it while I thought it was a Z1 Compact: I found statements online that said that it is still possible, even if Sony thinks it's not, but it will likely disable the camera and a few other things.

Comment: Just tried it and the button on the website doesn't work. It just isn't clickable, no matter what I do. I even artificially made it clickable using JavaScript, but that still does nothing. I contacted Sony about this and the problem in this question now.

Comment: Update over a year later: I never got an answer. Since then I've switched to a different phone. I still have the old one and use it once every few weeks, so if someone knows an answer, I would still be happy to hear it.